# Comparing GET Array Values to Recordset Loop Values

Tags: php, arrays, get, recordset

I am having no luck trying to compare values in an array passed as a GET to values in a database recordset do/while loop. I'm attempting to make a checkbox checked if any value in the GET array matches a recordset id. It works if you use only one interest id in the URL without a comma. Thank you.

My URLs are:
interestSearch.php?interests=3 (this works)
interestSearch.php?interests=3,8 (doesn't work)

```
<? require('db.php');

mysql_select_db($database_data);
$query_allInterests = "SELECT * FROM interests"; 
$allInterests = mysql_query($query_allInterests, $data) or die(mysql_error());
$row_allInterests = mysql_fetch_assoc($allInterests);
$totalRows_allInterests = mysql_num_rows($allInterests);

?>


<form method="get">

<? do { ?>
<input <?

if(isset($_GET['interests']) && $_GET['interests'] != "") {


$theCounter = 0;
$theArray = array($_GET['interests']);



        foreach ($theArray as $value) {             
//          if ($value == $row_allInterests['id']) {$theCounter++;} 
            if (in_array($row_allInterests['id'], $theArray)) {$theCounter++;}      
        }





if($theCounter > 0){echo "checked";}


}


?> name="<? echo $row_allInterests['id']; ?>" class="doCheck" type="checkbox" id="<? echo $row_allInterests['id']; ?>" value="<? echo $row_allInterests['id']; ?>" /> <? echo $row_allInterests['interest']; ?><br />
<? } while ($row_allInterests = mysql_fetch_assoc($allInterests)); ?>

</form>
```

Comment: (I removed the SOLVED from the title, as the community's indication of a solved question is the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$theArray = array($_GET['interests']);
```

Use

```
$theArray = explode( ',', $_GET['interests']);
```